# An example of a sequence of finite projections

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ be a vn-algebra.  Suppose that $x$ is an isometry with $\inf_{n\geq1} x^nx^{*n}=0$ (Note that $x^nx^{*n}$ are all projections). Let $e$ be a (non-zero) finite projection and put $q_n$ to be the left support of $x^{*n}e$.

> Q. Does there exist any vn-algebra in which $q_n=e$ for all $n$?

Rem. For a given $y\in A$, the left support of $y$ is the smallest projection $p$ with $py=y$.